# My mobile menu Jquery script only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, menu

Hi I'm new to jquery and just trying to put a simple script together to show/hide my mobile menu on click. It works fine however, it only works once until you refresh your browser.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
    $(".nav").addClass("hidenav");
    $(".menutrigger").click(function () {
        $(".nav").removeClass("hidenav").addClass("slidenav");

$(".menutrigger").click(function () {
        $(".nav").removeClass("slidenav").addClass("hidenav");
        });

        });
});
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .slidenav {
        display: block;
    }
    .hidenav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are defining multiple click events

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        //your code here
        $(".nav").addClass("hidenav");
        var flag = 0;
        $(".menutrigger").click(function()
        {
            if(flag == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                $(".nav").removeClass("hidenav").addClass("slidenav");
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
                $(".nav").removeClass("slidenav").addClass("hidenav");
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

declaring multiple onClick events won't work and will be overridden by last one. you can do all those things in on onclick callback by checking whether your class is there or not

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //your code here
    $(".nav").addClass("hidenav");
    $(".menutrigger").click(function () {
        if ($(".nav").hasClass("hidenav")){
           $(".nav").removeClass("hidenav").addClass("slidenav");
        } else if ($(".nav").hasClass("slidenav")){
           $(".nav").removeClass("slidenav").addClass("hidenav");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried toggleClass ?

```
$('.menutrigger').click(function (e) {
     $('.demo').toggleClass("hidenav");
});
```

it will compress your code to just 1 line.

have a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdniki/UaT3P/)

To know more about .toggleClass(). see the [jQuery API doc](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: Thank-You I will look into this